# How to translate an array of 0-1 values to 2-dimensional array of Cell references

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new to programming and I'm working on a java program where a user enters a string message of alphabet words and the string is converted into a 2D array of cells.

I used a method to convert the message into an array of 0-1 values. Here's an example of using this method with the letter "E"

```
1111111
1000000
1000000
1000000
1111000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1111111
```

Entries with 1 represent cells of the two-dimensional array that must have a foreground (red) color and those with 0 a background (white) color

Now I need to define a method that takes the 2-Dim array of integers returned by the method and then returns a 2-Dim array of Cells where zeros are mapped to cells with a white color and ones are mapped to Cells with a red color.

I have no idea on how to approach this method. I need a hint or a nudge in the right direction to get me started.

Edit:

This is my code so far:

public DataManager(String message) {

```
    for(int i = 0; i<message.length(); i++){

        int[][] text = Alphabet.toIntArray(message.charAt(i));  

    }
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to get the integers returned by Alphabet.toIntArray method.

This is what I mean by "2D array of cells"

The string "TURTLE" should be

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxnYI.jpg)

Comment: What is a Cells. Is that a class?

Comment: Add some code showing how Cell and this array are defined and initialized

Comment: If you have a method to convert single letters, convert all the letters in the message into2d-Arrays and zip 'em linewise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to iterate over each value in your array, create a new Cell for each value with the appropriate attributes, and add these to the same position in a new array. Something like this:

```
Cell[][] cellArray = new Cell[inputArray.length][inputArray[0].length]();
for (int i=0; i<inputArray.length; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<inputArray[0].length; j++) {
    Cell cell = new Cell();
    if (inputArray[i][j] == 0) {
      // Set cell attributes for 0 values
    } else {
      // Set cell attributes for 1 values
    }
    cellArray[i][j] = cell;
  }
}
```

Please note this is just a very rough example to give you a point in the right direction. Hope it helps

Comment: OP here. Thanks for this! Got my juices flowing and pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Good stuff, glad it helps! Can you please accept this as the answer if you think it's what you were looking for?

Comment: Do I just click green check?

Comment: Sorry, just saw your comment but I guess you figured it out. Thanks for that